# Construção do conhecimento dos objetos em DDD

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Encontrei no github um projeto de exemplo de DDD do Vaughn Vernon. Ainda não tive a oportunidade de comprar o livro dele e ler inteiro, mas uma coisa que me deixou curioso é o fato de existirem *muitos* objetos diferentes sendo definidos. E quando eu falo *muitos* são muitos mesmo.

Em um dos contextos delimitados dele tem 68 objetos. E isso eu estou falando só do modelo de domínio, sem contar ainda outros objetos necessários. Quando falo objeto eu estou simplesmente querendo generalizar: isso inclui entidades, objetos de valor, agregados, repositórios, etc.

A dúvida que isso me gerou foi a seguinte: eu particularmente acho humanamente impossivel começar uma aplicação e saber que pra ela fazer o que tem que fazer vão ser necessários tantos objetos assim. Quando eu vi isso eu pensei "tudo bem, mas como eu saberia que precisa disso tudo?"

E é ai que eu quero saber: a identificação desses objetos vem diretamente da linguagem ubiqua e por isso a importancia dela? Ou seja, eles representam necessariamente conceitos presentes  na linguagem ubiqua?

E principalmente, o conhecimento desses objetos é construido iterativamente? Ou seja, não se espera que de cara saibamos tudo isso, no começo sabemos só uma parte e aí a cada iteração com o avanço do entendimento do domínio entendemos quais outros objetos são necessários?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> É impossível começar uma aplicação e saber que pra ela fazer o que tem que fazer vão ser necessários tantos objetos assim.

---

> A identificação desses objetos vem diretamente da linguagem ubíqua e por isso a importancia dela. Ou seja, eles representam necessariamente conceitos presentes na linguagem ubíqua .

---

> E principalmente, o conhecimento desses objetos é construído iterativamente. Ou seja, não se espera que de cara saibamos tudo isso, no começo sabemos só uma parte e aí a cada iteração com o avanço do entendimento do domínio entendemos quais outros objetos são necessários.

---

**Como você pode ver, transformei suas perguntas em afirmações, e eis a sua resposta.**

É característica fundamental do **DDD** que o conhecimento do domínio seja aprofundado ao longo do projeto, e os modelos serão refatorados e evoluídos na medida em que se aprende mais sobre o domínio - o que acontece durante o projeto e não apenas no começo dele.

Isto também é característica de qualquer projeto **[Ágil](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/)**.

Quanto a ter muitos objetos se deve justamente ao fato de que um projeto DDD visa resolver um problema complexo, e um problema complexo tem sempre muitos elementos.

## Atento:

Assim como todas as boas idéias na nossa indústria, O DDD tem o objetivo de pôr pra pensar muito mais do que entregar mastigado.

Sugestão: leia o [livro do Eric Evans](http://amzn.com/0321125215) - esta é a certidão de nascimento do DDD. Você sairá com todas as tuas 200 dúvidas atuais respondidas e vai adquirir outras duas mil novas dúvidas. E isso será uma ótima experiência.